# How to add custom django admin site and urls without the prefix in every pattern?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to include the urls of my custom admin site of one of my apps in a Django project. I would like the path to be `foo-admin/...`. I managed to do so by including this prefix in all urlpatterns in the app's `urls.py`. However if I try to add the prefix to the project's `urls.py` and have only the suffixes in the app's urls, it breaks. It's something like this:

##### This works:

###### Project's `urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('my_app.urls')),
]
```

###### `my_app/urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('foo-admin/', my_app_admin_site.urls),
    path('foo-admin/foo/', views.some_view),
    path('foo-admin/foo/<slug>/', views.MyGenericView.as_view()),
]
```

##### This doesn't work:

###### Project's `urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('foo-admin/', include('my_app.urls')),
]
```

###### `my_app/urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', my_app_admin_site.urls),
    path('foo/', views.some_view),
    path('foo/bar/<slug>/', views.MyGenericView.as_view()),
]
```

The error I'm encountering is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /foo-admin/
Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'my_app'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/(?P<app_label>auth|app1|app2|django_mfa|axes)/$']
```

Comment: This is not about finding the view. This is the *view* itself that raises the error since it aims to *reverse* a URL, for example because of a `{% url ... %}` tag, or a `redirect(...)` or `reverse(...)` or `reverse_lazy(...)` that is been triggered by your `my_app_admin_site.urls`.

Comment: Did you by any chance added an `app_name` for one of your `urls.py`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsemyes. On `my_apps/urls.py` I have declared `app_name = 'my_app'`

Comment: what if you use `path('', include('my_app_admin_site.urls', name='auth')),` instead of `path('', my_app_admin_site.urls),` ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem then I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app_admin_site'`

Comment: If I unregister all my models from `my_app/admin.py` then the custom admin page loads ok. But by the moment I register `my_app_admin_site.register(MyModel)`, then the admin pages crashes with the mentioned error. I can't figure out why. All tutorials I've seen do it like that.